# OpenGL mesh intersection disturbance

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, shader

I have this weird issue in my program where the intersection between to meshes gets really messed up the further away I go. What is this phenomenon called and how do I fix it.

Here is a picture of it 
[image: illustration]

Comment: I can't tell what's happening in that image or what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). Use higher-res depth buffer.

But it could also mean that your mesh(es) has co-planar faces; you'd fix that by offsetting affected faces by a little.

Comment: Right. I already use a 24-bit depth buffer, and my zFar and zNear clipping isn't that ridiculous. So I guess it has to do with the faces. At the moment the water plane only consist of two triangles forming a quad, could that be the cause of this problem? the terrain should be fine. Thanks for your answer btw :-)

Comment: Not by itself alone, what else is there? I'm interested: what are your far/near values?

Comment: Near = 1.0 
far = 300.0

I've tried changing them, but it doesn't seem to help either way.